# Carry out update function on multiple lines in textarea

Tags: javascript, php

I have a textarea that posts each line to a database and then pulls that data to display it on a separate text area. I have a function that when called calls a php update function. This updates the line in the database corresponding to the line in the textarea. What I want to do is when this update function is called, I want all the lines to be updated, not just the one that is selected. This is because at the moment I have to manually select each line to update if a change is made anywhere to enusre the lines and indentation are the same.

```
    <script>
    var lineNo = 0;
    var lineText = "";
    var ta;
    var numOfSpaces;


   function update(e) {
       ta = $("#textEditor")[0];
     lineNo = ta.value.substr(0, ta.selectionStart).split(/\r?\n|\r/).length;
      lineText = ta.value.split(/\r?\n|\r/)[lineNo - 1];
       numOfSpaces = lineText.split(/\s/).length - 1;


      console.log(" line num: " +lineNo+ " line data: " + lineText);



        $.ajax({

         url: "update1.php",
         method: "POST",
         data: {lineN: lineNo, lineT: lineText},
         dataType: 'text',
         success: function(data){

          console.log(data);
         }
       });
     }

           $('#textarea').keydown(update).mousedown(update);
```

The above is the function which catches the text at a line and the corresponding line number. It passes the information to the following php file

```
    <?php


    $linec = $_POST['lineT'];
    $linenumber = $_POST['lineN']



     $update = "UPDATE Code_Stream1 SET Line_Code='$linec' where LineNumber='$linenumber' ";

    $resultinsert = $conn->query($update);

    echo $update;


?>
```

ps I have a connection to the database but didn't include above

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand your question, but couldn't you simply use `.setSelectionRange` on the textarea to select all text?

```js
$('#textEditor').on('focus', function(e) {
    // setTimeout skips to the next tik in the eventLoop
    // preventing timing issues in some browser
    setTimeout(function() {
        e.currentTarget.setSelectionRange(0, e.currentTarget.value.length);
    }, 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="textEditor" rows="4">
    Line 1
    Line 2
    Line 3
    Line 4
</textarea>
```

Comment: I don't think that quite worked for me. What I may need is a way for the UPDATE statement to UPDATE the $linec and $linenumber for each value of $linenumber each time that it is called

Comment: to clarify: do you want ALL lines in the textarea to be sent to the PHP script each time something changes?

Comment: Yes I was thinking either send all lines in the textarea to the PHP script or make the PHP script execute for each line, if the latter is possible

Comment: Not sure if you won't run into issues because you're sending so many requests to your server via AJAX (especially because you're sending requests on every keystroke), so it might be a better idea to process the lines on PHP's side and sending them to the script as an array, no?